# Get part of file name and insert into Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have setup a sheet to copy 1 page, and then create a new workbook with that data and save it as a new file name.

My code for the saving the file is -

```
    NewName = "HotterPGPalletDespatch - REF " & Format$(Date, "MMDDYYYY") _
     & "-" & Format(CStr(Now),     "hhmm") & ""

       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New\" & NewName, FileFormat _
        :=51, CreateBackup:=False
```

I want to take the Date/Time after the Word Ref and insert this into Cell G2.

How could I do this? (I don't want it to get the current date/time again as this may change so I need it to have the specific numbers from the file path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the workbook has been saved in the appropriate name format, use this formula in G2.

`=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(CELL("filename"), FIND("REF ",CELL("filename"))+4, 99), ".", REPT(" ", 99)), 99))`